# Does the \bibliography command add a page break afterward?

Tags: bibliographies, sectioning, page-breaking, sections-paragraphs

I am trying to add an entry from my .bib file into a document. After the `\bibliography` command is issued, the following sections starts in a new page. I have looked around but have not been able to find out about page breaks *after* the References section, given that the usual expected place for it is at the end of the document.

Why is the page break happening and how can I prevent it?

My document <strike>structure</strike> is dead simple:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{Author (year): Name of the article I am reviewing}
\author{Ricardo}
%
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[1]
\end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\refname}{\section*{SectionNo1}}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\nocite{reKkey}
\section*{SectionNo2}
\section*{SectionNo3}
\section*{SectionNo4}
\section*{SectionNo5}
\section*{SectionNo6}
\section*{SectionNo7}
\section*{SectionNo8}
\section*{SectionNo9}
\section*{SectionNo10}
\end{document}
```

*New info*
Furthermore, I am compiling to PDF on MacTeX TeXLive 2009 on AucTeX 11.86. Using the `fullpage` package does not change the behavior, so I commented it out. I just started my document skeleton, so this is, literally, all I have at the time.

The page break disappears if I write anything under any of the sections 2 through 4 (2 through 8 using the `fullpage` package. With this new information, I don't expect the page break to be a problem anymore. However, I am still interested in knowing why this is happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with your example above and an examples.bib and a citation. Try to make a real, complete example that demonstrates your problem instead of simply showing your document "structure". You can insert arbitrary text with the lipsum package or insert spaces with `\vspace*`-commands.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer, I updated the document structure to reflect what I actually have. My document is exactly that simple. I don't suppose the names of the sections will have any impact on the result, specially since they are three-words long at the longest. I noticed the page break behavior changed when I added more text to most any of the sections past SectionNo2. I did not try to manually add space with `\vspace*` because it feels too much like a hack to correct something that should default to being _right_ from the start. I mean, I had no way to predict that a page break would happen.

Comment: I didn't meant you should insert \vspace to correct your problem, but as a tool to demonstrate it. With e.g.`\vspace*{10\baselineskip}` you can avoid to have to enter 10 lines of text in your example. lockstep has explained the source of your problem: LaTeX has to break somewhere and after the bibliography was better then after a `\section*`.

Comment: Oh, My mistake. I thought you meant I could use negative spacing to bring the next section above the page break. Your explanation makes more sense than what I had interpreted. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX strongly discourages page breaks after section headings. By writing `\section*` nine times without adding "normal" text after any of these headings, you practically forced LaTeX to add a page break after the last bibliography entry (which counts as "normal" text). Writing anything after a section heading adds a desirable page break afterwards.

Comment: Well, this makes sense. Thanks! I learned something new today. Also, thanks for editing the tags.